# How to access TFS 2013's $(Rev:.r) property from within a Build Template?

Tags: tfs

The default build template for TFS has a format of $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

This translates to something like BuildName_20141111.1 for the first build of the day, BuildName_20141111.2 for the second and so on that.

That's all well and good but what I'd like to do is pull out that .r and insert it into the assembly before it's compiled by the build server.

I've already edited the build template to update the various AssemblyInfo.cs files and such and that's working fine. Right now we are toying with the idea of Major.Minor.yyDDD (Day of year).r but the catch is that very last part - how do we get $(Rev:.r) from within a build template?

I've tried looking through the various environmental variables and I can pull out the entire Build definition string (i.e. BuildName_20141111.1) but really all I want is that .1 (or more specifically "1"). Is there a way to do this programmatically? Is there an environment variable I've missed? Or is there a way that I can actually access things like $(Rev:.r) directly?

I am relatively new to TFS but this is the last hurdle before I can move a lot of projects to it.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively need to parse this off yourself from the BuildName parameter. If you are using TFS 2013 you can do it in PowerShell. Prior versions need a customized build template.

There are prebuilt solutions to this. Best is the TfsVersion activity or the VersionAssemblies.ps1 that is provided as part of the TFS Community Build Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured this was going to be the case but was hoping there'd be a simpler way to grab it.